# Storing multiple XGBoost models

Tags: python, numpy, model, xgboost

I have a dataset that is a time series. I would like to train one XGB model for each day in the timeseries. I wanted to use a for loop, but I'm not sure how to store all of the models properly and be able to call them later on. This is what I had so far:

```
for date in range(minDate, maxDate):
   model[date] = xgb.train(params, data)
```

But I'm not sure what `model[date]` should be? Can it be an numpy array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionnary with the dates as keys:

```py
model = {}
for date in range(minDate, maxDate):
   model[date] = xgb.train(params, data)
```

Then later you can call any model for a given date RandomDate, let's say to predict an output given some inputs

```py
model[RandomDate].predict(inputs)
```